# Firebase analytics disk write failures

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

Working with the Firebase SDK on iOS and have an app in some live testing using Apple TestFlight. Some users are reporting some weird behaviour so I started looking into their logs and saw there was some odd things going on with Firebase. Here are some snippets from the logs:

> kernel[0] : Sandbox: (455) deny(1) file-write-create /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FIREBASE_UNIQUE_INSTALL

```
<Notice>: <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
<Notice>: <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (google link removed)
 <Notice>: <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analtics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist

<Notice>: Sandbox: Studio(455) deny(1) file-write-create /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FIREBASE_UNIQUE_INSTALL
```

Not long after the user auth changes and the callback comes in and I log it.

```
 <Notice>:    <FIRUser: 0x13e06b110>
```

Then more firebase logging.

```
 <Notice>: <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
```

I need the auth token for some server authentication so the completion handler comes in and I log it.

```
 <Warning>: [STConfiguration] firebase auth token: <hidden token>
```

After that, i start downloading some storage files, where there's more weirdness, i get lot's of ssl handshake errors (ATS is handled correctly and it's hard to debug where these are coming ).

```
 <Warning>: CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
```

Then another Firebase oddity.

```
 <Notice>: Sandbox: <appname hidden>(455) deny(1) file-write-create /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FIREBASE_LAST_TIMESTAMP
```

It goes on like this for a while. Odd thing is, some Firebase stuff works fine, others seem to be failling for no apparent reason. The ssl handshake issues seem to point to a device being connected to a wireless network that is not connected to the internet, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in the latest Firebase Analytics version.

Comment: I just downloaded the latest version 3.11.1 and I'm getting this error on iOS

Comment: Do you mean this one?
<Notice>: Sandbox: <appname hidden>(455) deny(1) file-write-create /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FIREBASE_LAST_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 0):

may related to a known bug.

> The last line 
>   `<Notice>: Sandbox: myappname(2327) deny(1) file-write-create /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/FIREBASE_LAST_TIMESTAMP`
>   is a known bug and we are on it.

please see: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/34#issuecomment-230823806